# No entiendo el uso del operador flecha porque repite la variable al principio y al final

Tags: php, operador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¿por qué las variables repiten item con operador flecha si ya esta indicando que es iguala item en la variable $oldcart?

```
public function __construct($oldcart){
  $this->items= $oldcart->items;
  $this->cantidad_total= $oldcart->cantidad_total;
  $this->precio_total= $oldcart->precio_total;
}
```

En el storeditem porque repite precio cuando asocia producto

```
public function add($producto, $id){
  $storedItem= ['cantidad' => 0, 'precio' => $producto->precio, 'items' => $producto];
  if($this->items){
    if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
      $storedItem= $this->items[$id];
    }
  }
  $storedItem['cantidad']++;
  $storedItem['precio']= $producto->precio * $storedItem['cantidad'];
  $this->items[$id]= $storedItem;
  $this->cantidad_total++;
  $this->precio_total += $producto->precio;


}// FIN FUNCIÓN ADD
```

porque storeditem primero es igual a items[i$d] y luego al reves

no entiendo mucho porque usan el operador flecha asi lo poco que se es que dicho operador se usa para acceder a metodos y variables cuando se crea un objeto

Comment: si es un parametro del constructor para cuando se inicialice el objeto pasar por parametro alguna petición

Comment: Si item, cantidad_total y precio_ total son propiedades de la clase que se llama carrito, edite e incluí una imagen de toda la clase

Comment: si en la funcion agregar primero va asi  $storedItem= $this->items[$id]; y luego asi $this->items[$id]= $storedItem;

Comment: La pregunta está planteada de una forma muy confusa, no logra entenderse cuál es la duda o problema que tienes.

Comment: Con esto: `$storedItem= ['cantidad' => 0, 'precio' => $producto->precio, 'items' => $producto];` estás asignando `$producto` (objeto completo) a la propiedad `items`, tal vez debería ser `'items' => $producto->nombre` o la propiedad que requieras.

Answer (score 1):

recuerda que cuando estamos haciendo uso del operador objeto `->` (el operador flecha es `=>`) en forma `this->something` es por que estamos haciendo uso de `POO`, teniendo eso claro se puede decir que lo que le estas diciendo al interprete es lo siguiente `deEsteObjeto referenteA talVariable` donde `deEsteObjeto` es el equivalente a poner el contexto `this`, `talVariable` es equivalente a `->` y por ultimo `talVariable` es `something` (la variable que estas asignando), ahora un ejemplo practico con el codigo que tienes.

```
class Carrito{ #Esta es tu clase (tambien nos referimos a ella como contexto u objeto cuando hablamos de sus variables y entorno)
    public item = null; 
    public $cantidad total=0;
    public $precio_total=0;
}

public function __construct($oldcart){ #Pasas oldcart como objeto o JSON 
    $this->items= $oldcart->items; #Vas a asignar el valor de items al objeto/clase actual desde el objeto oldcart
    $this->cantidad_total= $oldcart->cantidad_total;#Vas a asignar el valor de cantidad_total al objeto/clase actual desde el objeto oldcart
    $this->precio_total= $oldcart->precio_total; #as a asignar el valor de precio_total al objeto/clase actual desde el objeto oldcart
}
```

Te dejo una mejor explicación de los tipos de variables

> **public** Acceso no restringido.
>
> **protected** El acceso es limitado a la clase que lo contiene o clases derivadas
>
> **private** E acceso es limitado a la clase que lo crea.

Considerando esa explicación lo que estas haciendo es asignarle al objeto `carrito` el atributp `item` que viene del objeto `oldcart` en el atributo `item`

Comment: quieres decir que en este caso como viene de un parametro se tiene que volver a indicar item de esta forma this -> item=$oldcart -> item

Comment: Recuerda que no es el mismo elemento, en el caso del objeto a la izquierda del `=` es el objeto propio del contexto/clase, mientras que a la derecha es el objeto que pasas como parametro, de hecho supongamos que en tu clase lo llamas `item` pero en tu parametro lo llamas `articulo` en este caso tu asignación de variable quedaria como `$this->item = $oldcart->articulo` donde `$this->item` es la asignación de la variable item de la clase y a su vez `$oldcart->articulo` es el valor que estas asignando.

Comment: ok mas o menos capto la idea tendre que estudiar mas sobre laravel porque la forma de programar ahi es mas avanzada

Comment: De hecho el uso del operador objeto funciona en PHP puro tambien.